# how to remove unicode string "[u'string]" when I write CSV file

Tags: python, scrapy

how to remove unicode string "[u'string]" when I write CSV file.

```
**this is my spider:**
import pdb
import FileManager
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from centerfireguns.items import CenterfiregunsItem
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.http import Request
new_filemanager = FileManager.File_Manager()
class FiregunsSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'centerfireguns'
allowed_domains = ['centerfireguns.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.centerfireguns.com/firearms.html']

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(@class, "i-next")][1]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls = hxs.select('//a[contains(@class,"product-image")]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        new_url = urljoin("http://www.centerfireguns.com/", url)
        item = CenterfiregunsItem()
        item['ad_url'] = new_url
        request = Request(new_url, callback = self.parse_detail)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request


def parse_detail(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']

    #<div class="product-name"><h1 itemprop="name">Adcor Defense BEAR 223 16 OPT RDY</h1>
    item['title'] = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-name")]//h1/text()').extract()

    #<div class="product-shop"><span class="regular-price" id="product-price-21339"> <span class="price" itemprop="price">$1,389.00</span> </span>
    item['price'] = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-shop")]//span[contains(@itemprop,"price")][1]/text()').extract()

    #<div class="sku"><span>Model #: </span>2013040</div>
    item['model'] = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "sku")]/text()').extract()

    #<img id="image" itemprop="image" src="http://www.centerfireguns.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/292x320/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/d/adcor-defense-2013040-tactical-rifles.jpg">
    item['img_url'] = hxs.select('//img[contains(@id, "image")]/@src').extract()

    #<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    item['specification'] = hxs.select('//table[contains(@id, "product-attribute-specs-table")]/text()').extract()

    #<div id="product_tabs_description_tabbed_contents"><h6>Full Description</h6><ol><h2>Details</h2><div class="std">
    item['description'] = hxs.select('//div[contains(@id, "product_tabs_description_tabbed_contents")]//div[contains(@class, "std")]/text()').extract()

    #new_filemanager.writeFile("/home/user1/Public/www/GajenderData/SCRIPTS/pythonprog/ganesh/centerfireguns_detail.csv",str(title) + "\n")
    yield item
```

**This is pipeline.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
class CenterfiregunsPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('/home/user1/Public/www/GajenderData/SCRIPTS/pythonprog/ganesh/centerfireguns_detail.csv', 'wb'))
    self.myCSV.writerow(['ad_url','title', 'model','price','img_url','specification','description'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.myCSV.writerow([item['ad_url'].encode('utf-8'),item['title'].encode('utf-8'),item['model'].encode('utf-8'),item['price'].encode('utf-8'),item['img_url'].encode('utf-8'),item['specification'].encode('utf-8'),item['description'].encode('utf-8')])
    return item
```

**when I use .encode('utf-8') I have got this error.please check below**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 54, in _process_chain
return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
d.callback(input)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 362, in callback
self._startRunCallbacks(result)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 458, in _startRunCallbacks
self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/user1/Public/www/GajenderData/SCRIPTS/pythonprog/ganesh/centerfireguns/centerfireguns/pipelines.py", line 14, in process_item
self.myCSV.writerow([item['ad_url'].encode('utf-8'),item['title'].encode('utf-8'),item['model'].encode('utf-8'),item['price'].encode('utf-8'),item['img_url'].encode('utf-8'),item['specification'].encode('utf-8'),item['description'].encode('utf-8')])
**exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'**
```

I am beginner in python

Comment: I think  before `.encode('utf-8')`, you should index first. I mean it should be smt like : `item['ad_url'][0].encode('utf-8')`

Comment: One of the items that you think is a string is actually a list.

Comment: Following on from Ignacio's comment for each `item['xxx']` use `print type(item['xxxx']) to find which one is tripping you up.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet as part of a function as part of a function in a pet project of mine that does the removal exactly  what you're looking for by declaring a dictionary with the values you wish to remove and then use replace method over th the target file and the items in the dictionary...  I do use it in a text file so you have to tweak it with CSV writer and reader but the idea is...

```
    name = "file.csv"    
    infile = name
    outfile = name + "_clean.csv"

    delete_list = ["['", "']"]
    fin = open(infile)
    fout = open(outfile, "w+")
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

also,  maybe even more pythonic-hackish  would be to  strip and then join  items  right before you to define them... example

```
#...
tit = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-name")]//h1/text()').extract()
tit = [x.strip() for in in tit]
tit = ''.join()
prc = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-shop")]//span[contains(@itemprop,"price")][1]/text()').extract()
prc = [x.strip() for x in prc]
prc = ''.join(prc)

item = response.meta['item']

item['title'] = tit

item['price'] = prc
#...
```

This way you can save yourself from even having to use the pipeline (if the sole reason for the pipeline was for the encoding)... otherwise you can do away with the encoding in your pipeline if it serves you a desired purpose... may I ask why the need for the pipeline?